# Default Users for Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I’m trying to secure my Databases and wanted to know what are the default or built in users for Postgres databases?

Am I able to change the usernames or remove these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default User is created during installation of the server instance. But you can query for a list of all current Users using this query:

```
SELECT usename AS role_name,
  CASE 
     WHEN usesuper AND usecreatedb THEN 
       CAST('superuser, create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
     WHEN usesuper THEN 
        CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
     WHEN usecreatedb THEN 
        CAST('create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
     ELSE 
        CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
  END role_attributes
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user
ORDER BY role_name desc;
```

For more information please see [this article](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-list-users/).

You can change the Users and their passwords using `ALTER USER`, as discussed [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-set-the-default-user-password-in-postgresql/). You can also disable the login for the default User as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926854/5059085).

Comment: Thanks that code shows me all the users on my Database

Answer (score 1):

A default installation of Postgres 13 only contains a single role called `postgres` which has the `Superuser`, `Create role`, `Create DB`, `Replication`, and `Bypass RLS` attributes. The default installation is also configured (using `pg_hba.conf`) to allow anyone logged in to the operating system as the user `postgres` to connect to the database as the role `postgres`. This is so that, by default, no passwords need be configured -- the operating system is relied on for security.

You should leave the `postgres` account in place. There's also no point in revoking access to the database from the operating user `postgres` by editing `pg_hba.conf` as that OS user can see all the database files anyway -- so it would be trivial to copy the data at the OS level.

You should create your own accounts to access the database.

One method I recommend is to create a `sudo` role with the `noinherit` attribute. Then `grant postgres to sudo`. Finally grant `sudo` to any users that occasionally need to be a `superuser`. They can gain that by issuing `set role postgres;` before executing any other commands. Note that because of the `noinherit`, the role `postgres` won't be active on connection to the database.

Similarly, you can and should also create an `admin` role with `noinherit`. You can grant the owners of your data to it, so that a user needing to execute DDL on a particular database can login and then execute `set role <tableowner>;` and then execute the DDL.

Comment: Yes I see my default user in the pg_hba.conf also, thank you for the security pointers for securing user access to the database